# Highlighting the background color of a text with fading animation after 1 sec

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-animation, core-graphics

I am now implementing an ebook in which I have to highlight each word when the audio of the text plays. The highlighted color will fade off after 2 sec. How can we add a background color for the text. I am not using UILabel since there are lengthy text with many sentences.
How can we do this? Anyone please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            I think u should use UIWebView rather than UITextView,  and dynamically u can 
    highlight the text by adding html tags and style tag around a particular string. But
 for that u need to track which string or text audio is playing. Both of these operations
 should be performed simultaneously,i.e., Audio Playing and attaching tags aroynd the tags. 

Now if u want to fade off the color of the text after two seconds , simply call function
after delay of two seconds, in which u can change the text color back to earlier on.
 To call function after delay u should go for

[self performSelector:@selector(changeTooriginalColor) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

Your Second Question's anawer:

```
UIWebView *wizardSpeechWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,320,265)];
wizardSpeechWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
wizardSpeechWebView.opaque = NO; 
wizardSpeechWebView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:wizardSpeechWebView];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How can we make we clear the UIWebView's white background color?